# Lint Error for pod library Swift 4 Xcode 9

Tags: cocoapods, xcode9

I'm creating a pod for my swift 4 for library.

I run `pod lib create IntentedLibraryName` which generates the workspace. Then I did the necessary modifications to the files `IntentedLibraryName.podspec`, and moving my library swift files to  the path *IntentedLibraryName/Classes/*.

To test out if the pod works,  I've Build and `pod install` from the Example project and everything works as intended.

Now, I run `pod lib lint IntentedLibraryName.podspec --verbose` then I got

> (1 failure) === BUILD TARGET IntentedLibraryName OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
>
> Check dependencies The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. This setting can be set in the build settings editor. The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. This setting can be set in the build settings editor

I did the following hoping it would fix it:

In the `Pod project`, From  `Build Settings` > `Swift Compiler- Language` > `Swift Language Version` from Swift unspecified to Swift 4.0.

I added and committed all changes along the tag (i.e `git tag 0.0.1`)  and push all it with --tags. (i.e `git push -u origin dev --tags`)

I run the linting command again, and **still the same issue**.

I even try to`echo 4.0 > .swift-version` save all commit and push it again. NADA

Also tried `s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_VERSION' => '4.0' }` NADA

````
## CocoaPods Environment

ℹ Please replace this with the output of `pod env`.
e.g. via `pod env | pbcopy`
### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.4.0.beta.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin16]
    RubyGems : 2.5.1
        Host : Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G1023)
       Xcode : 9.0 (9A235)
         Git : git version 2.8.1
Ruby lib dir : /Users/lamour/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib
Repositories : bahlo - https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif @ d26325392aefe7822dea79a757d4e300c694d010
               master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ f2169476eead8b1a9d898ff73c5eba516504ed78
```

### Installation Source

```
Executable Path: /Users/lamour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/pod
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.1
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```
````

### Project that demonstrates the issue

Please link to a project we can download that reproduces the issue.
You can delete this section if your issue is unrelated to build problems,
i.e. it's only an issue with CocoaPods the tool.

> I do think its an issue with Xcode 9.0 because I've created empty project, still same thing happened.

Thanks for the help :)

> **Issue Fixed**

The issue had nothing to do with `Xcode 9` but it was with `cocoapods`. I did [uninstall cocoapods](https://superuser.com/questions/686317/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine) from my machine and install it again. Once you done make sure you had the `echo 4.0 > .swift-version`. Voila :)

Comment: thanks, reinstall cocoapod fixed my problem

Comment: It seems that the `cocoapods` version was conflicting @User9527

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 4.0 > swift-version
```

should be

```
echo 4.0 > .swift-version
```

right (NB the leading dot)?

I had the same problem and for whichever reason, in my *.swift-version* file there was a strange

```
2.4 =>
```

in it (sic).

After I changed it to

```
4.0
```

, everything worked.

Example project here:

https://github.com/karstengresch/CleanroomLogger (actually a dumb fork of CleanRoomLogger which I want to use with Cocoapods).

Comment: I missed the dot while typing but I will check it out soon

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Could you please post the project URL so I could investigate more deeply? Or is it just a clone of https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif which you want to fork?

I've created a dumb (and empty) test project here: https://github.com/karstengresch/IntentedLibraryName and could run the linter w/o probs.

One caveat: My username in the repository URL was wrong (i.e. with a hyphen, probably coming from some environment variable used by Cocoapods).

Comment: I fixed the issue, i had it what need it to done in the question. Thanks for the help

Comment: Happy you could solve your problem. I'd be more than happy if you could either share your solution description in the sense of how you solved it (if different to my answer) and/or upvote my answer.
Thanks very much!

Comment: the answer is within the question just read the last paragraph. Thanks